# Route not found. PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to route in my own mvc framework. Simple route like /controller/action is working properly with following:
index.php

```
$router = new Core\Router();
```

//Add the routes

```
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');
```

Router:

```
public function add($route, $params = [])
    {
        // Convert the route to a regular expression: escape forward slashes
        $route = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $route);

        // Convert variables e.g. {controller}
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', $route);

        // Convert variables with custom regular expressions e.g. {id:\d+}
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+):([^\}]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>\2)', $route);

        // Add start and end delimiters, and case insensitive flag
        $route = '/^' . $route . '$/i';

        $this->routes[$route] = $params;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the routes from the routing table
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoutes()
    {
        return $this->routes;
    }

    /**
     * Match the route to the routes in the routing table, setting the $params
     * property if a route is found.
     *
     * @param string $url The route URL
     *
     * @return boolean  true if a match found, false otherwise
     */
    public function match($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->routes as $route => $params) {
            if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {
                // Get named capture group values
                foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
                    if (is_string($key)) {
                        $params[$key] = $match;
                    }
                }

                $this->params = $params;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the currently matched parameters
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch the route, creating the controller object and running the
     * action method
     *
     * @param string $url The route URL
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function dispatch($url)
    {
        $url = $this->removeQueryStringVariables($url);

        if ($this->match($url)) {
            $controller = $this->params['controller'];
            $controller = $this->convertToStudlyCaps($controller);
            $controller = $this->getNamespace() . $controller;

            if (class_exists($controller)) {
                $controller_object = new $controller($this->params);

                $action = $this->params['action'];
                $action = $this->convertToCamelCase($action);

                if (is_callable([$controller_object, $action])) {
                    $controller_object->$action();

                } else {
                    throw new \Exception("Method $action (in controller $controller) not found");
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Controller class $controller not found");
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('No route matched.', 404);
        }
    }
```

But while i try to add another route like: /controller/id/action in my index.php
with:

```
$router->add('{controller}/{id:\d}/{action}');
```

It is showing route not found exception. What wrong am i doing here. Can anyone tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to go all the way with this, keep in mind most routing systems need to accommodate a fairly arbitrary number of routes, even thousands, and still perform well. This often means compiling all of the routes into a compact state machine, or a very complicated singular regular expression.

Comment: So the resulting regex is: `^(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<id>\d)\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+)$`. I think it should be `\d+`. Anyway, fast solution - take already working router, I like this [one](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) for example

Comment: What is the example url you are trying to route to? And it throws the "No route matched ." exception? Also, can you show your removeQueryStringVariables function, maybe it is fouling up the url?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I think that if and list in add method are required, and in match method `$param` argument needs to `$this->$params = $param` thats my bugs when I wrote that code.

```
class Router {

    protected $routes = [];
    protected $params  = [];

    public function add($route,$action) {

        $route = preg_replace('/^\//','',$route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\//','\\/',$route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/','(?<\1>[a-z0-9-]+)',$route);
        $route = '/^'. $route .'\/?$/i';

        $action = is_array($action) ? $action ['uses'] : $action;

        list($params['controller'] , $params['method']) = explode('@',$action);

        $this->routes[$route] = $params;
    }

      
    public function match($url) {
        foreach ($this->routes as $route => $param) {

            if(preg_match($route , $url , $matchess)) {

                    foreach ($matchess as $key => $match){
                        if(!is_numeric($key)) {
                            $param [$key] = $match;
                        }
                    }
                $this->params = $param;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getRoutes(): array {
        return $this->routes;
    }

    public function getParams() {
        return $this->params;
    }
}
```

Comment: i was learning MVC and i have same problem, i think that if and list in add method are required , and in match method $param argument needs to $this->$params = $param thats my bugs when i wrote that code.

Comment: Thanks, I just add it in your answer !